# Java drawing to JPanel Graphics, using byte array, blinking white

Tags: java

So I am trying to update a JPanel using a byte array with a specified byte/color
This is a very simple version.
When I start the program it's white for half a second, then becomes the right color, and then after 1 second it's going back to being white, I tried to print out the current color, and sometimes it's changing to '0'.
What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {
public static Random ran = new Random();
public static byte[] buffer;
public static int num = 0;
public static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
public static JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        num = 0;
        byte[] current_buffer = buffer.clone();

        for (int y = 0; y < panel.getHeight(); y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < panel.getWidth(); x++) {
                g.setColor(new Color(current_buffer[num], current_buffer[num], current_buffer[num]));
                g.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
                num++;
            }
        }

    }
};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(1200, 800);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    engine.run();
}

public static boolean running = true;
public static Thread engine = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        buffer = new byte[panel.getWidth() * panel.getHeight()];
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
            buffer[i] = (byte) 34;
        }
        while (running) {
            panel.repaint(10L);
        }
    }
};
```

}

Comment: Use paintComponent rather than paint

Comment: It still doesn't work :(  blink for a second and then turns white

Comment: Use a SwingWorker insteadof a Thread or use SwingUtilities.invokeLater() to call repaint int the Swing event queue. You also can use a swing Timer to refresh every 30 or 60 img/sec

Comment: That does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Not really understanding your logic:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
        buffer[i] = (byte) 34;
    }
```

You assign the same value to the buffer.

Then you create a Color object using the same value.

```
 g.setColor(new Color(current_buffer[num], current_buffer[num], current_buffer[num]));
```

So every pixel will be the same Color.

And since the buffer is always built with the same values, the color won't change.

Also, why would you use

```
byte[] current_buffer = buffer.clone();
```

You are just using the values in the buffer, not updating the values in the buffer so I see no reason for the clone.

Don't use a Thread with a while loop. For animation you should be using a `Swing Timer`. When the Timer fires you update the values in the buffer and then invoke repaint().

> When I start the program it's white for half a second, then becomes the right color, and then after 1 second it's going back to being white,

I don't see that behaviour.

1. it blinks a light color
2. it stays painted at a darker color

The above makes sense because:

1. Your paintCompnent() method does not invoke super.paintComponent(...) to make sure the background is cleared
2. The array is not initialized to any values when it is created so the default value will be 0.
3. After the Thread takes over the array will alway contain the same value so the same color will be painted.

What do you expect it to do?

Comment: as I said this it's just a small version; I know all the colors will be the same; I just made this small version of the engine to try and make it work; I won't be doing the animations on this engine only update and do a few other math stuff on this thread, and then create another Thread with a semi-fixed update rate for the animations

Comment: Animation should be done with a Swing Timer, not a Thread! Updates to the state of the component need to be done on the EDT which is why you need the Timer, not a Thread. See edit.